# Do you always need a mock for ActivatedRoute?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

So I am doing some unit tests. And the following component I try to unit test:

```
export class EcheqDisplayComponent implements OnInit {
  echeq: EcheqSubmissionApi;
  orgId = 1;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    this.echeq = this.route.snapshot.data['submission'];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getAnswers(page: EcheqPageApi): any[] {
    return page.elements.map(element => this.echeq.answers[element.name]);
  }
```

And this is the unit test for it:

```
describe('EcheqDisplayComponent', () => {
  let component: EcheqDisplayComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<EcheqDisplayComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ],
      imports:[ParticipantEcheqModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([])

      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EcheqDisplayComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  fit('should create component', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

So I dont get errors.

But my question is. Is this the correct way to do ti?

Because is it not better to use a mock for ActivatedRoute?

An if yes, how to do it then the correct way?

Thank you

sO THIS IS the template of it:

```
<div class="echeq-display" *ngIf="echeq">
  <header class="echeq-display-header header">
    <div class="echeq-display-info">
      <h1 class="heading echeq-display-heading">
        {{ echeq.definition.title }}
      </h1>
      <div class="sub-heading echeq-display-subheading">
        <span class="echeq-display-creator">
          Toegekend door:
          {{ echeq.assignedByProfName ? echeq.assignedByProfName : 'Het Systeem' }}
        </span>
        <span class="echeq-display-date">{{
          echeq.definition.createdOnUtc | date: 'dd MMM'
        }}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <app-meta-box
      [metadata]="{
        numPages: echeq.definition.numPages,
        vPoints: echeq.definition.awardedVPoints
      }"
    ></app-meta-box>
  </header>
  <main class="echeq-display-questions body">
    <app-echeq-question
      *ngFor="let page of echeq.definition.pages; let i = index"
      [page]="page"
      [readonly]="true"
      [number]="i + 1"
      [answers]="getAnswers(page)"
    ></app-echeq-question>
  </main>
</div>
```

and the unit test like this:

```
 beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ],
      providers: [
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useClass: MockActivatedRoute }
      ],
      imports:[
        ParticipantEcheqModule

      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

and this is the app-meta-box component:

```
export class MetaData {
  numPages: number;
  vPoints: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-meta-box',
  templateUrl: './meta-box.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./meta-box.component.scss']
})
export class MetaBoxComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() metadata: MetaData;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply provide mock ActivatedRoute object with necessary variable set in "providers" property when "TestBed.configureTestingModule({...})" is called to configure testing module.

```
class MockActivatedRoute {
    public snapshot = { 
        data: {
           submission: {
             answers: {}
           }
        }
    };
}

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ ],
  providers: [
   { provide: ActivatedRoute, useClass: MockActivatedRoute }
  ]
  imports:[
    ParticipantEcheqModule,
    // RouterModule.forRoot([]) // Not required after mocking the "ActivatedRoute"
  ]
})
.compileComponents();
```

This way you can test your component for different values in activatedRoute.

Comment: Thank you for your answare. But then I will get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'numPages' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'numPages' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ng:///ParticipantEcheqModule/EcheqDisplayComponent.ngfactory.js:40:54)

Comment: But what is meaning the asnware property?

Comment: @savantCodeEngineer where is this "numPages" property in component under test? I don't see it anywhwere in  the EcheqDisplayComponent? Are you sure the error is related with EcheqDisplayComponent component only>?


Is "numPages"property expected in "submission.answers" property?